# If George Zimmerman wins his $100M lawsuit against Ben Crump, will he lose his license?

Tags: licensing, unlicensed-practice, bar-association

Currently, George Zimmerman is suing Ben Crump (and many others) for purposely using a fake witness against Zimmerman in the Martin case.

If he wins, which he most likely will as it is undeniable if one watches the documentary of the fake witness(The Trayvon Hoax: Unmasking the Witness Fraud that Divided America‬), could Ben Crump still lose his license?

If they settle, will the Bar Association still consider taking away his license?

Comment: What is "the documentary of the fake witness"?

Comment: @phoog "The Trayvon Hoax: Unmasking the Witness Fraud that Divided America‬" - Joel Gilbert. I believe you can now watch for free on YouTube.

Comment: Can you link to a news organization coverage of the case, preferably with no video?

Comment: Also for the sake of making this a question about law and not about a specific and devisive case you should probably remove the portion "which he most likely will as it is undeniable if one watches the documentary of the fake witness" as it's going to be more likely to get an inflammatory answer.

Comment: @hszmv It's already a question about the law; who cares if it's a question about a specific and divisive case?

Comment: "If he wins, which he most likely will as it is undeniable" The case is a long shot, not a clear win. The scope of an attorney's duties to adverse parties for which the attorney can be sued is very narrow, there are legal doctrines that discourage collateral litigation over statements made in court cases, etc. all stand in the way of recovery.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the lawsuit, but generally speaking, a court's finding that a lawyer falsified evidence would not directly result in the lawyer being disbarred, as the trial court does not have authority to regulate the practice of law.

Instead, a court that reached that conclusion -- either by a verdict, or because a judge was persuaded by the evidence without reaching a verdict -- would likely report that outcome to whatever organization is responsible for licensing attorneys in that jurisdiction.